# Where are installed the binaries of Texlive?

Tags: 12.04, installation, latex

After installing Texlive 2012 trought the `texlive-backports` ppa on Ubuntu 12.04, I cannot find it in `/usr/local/`.  Why?

I need to find the path to the binaries so I can add that to TeXstudio.

Comment: `which pdflatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is because it goes to `/usr/share`, but in any case, look for it with

```
locate texlive |more
```

(The `|more`bit is necessary because you'll get too many hits).

Comment: Sure enough, there it is in /share.  Thanks.

Comment: As a footnote, when I ran `locate texlive` (with or without the `|more`) the terminal came back with nothing...

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but I'm sure your package manager knows where the files from the packages are - no need to use locate.